# Type script type from prev

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I'm not sure which type to designate here.

"HowitterObject" in setHowitters is data and "...prev' is the continuous addition of data from howitterObject.

```js
 interface IhowitterMessage {
  message: string;
  createAt: number;
  id: string;
}

const Home = () => {
const [howitters, setHowitters] = useState<IhowitterMessage[]>([]);

  const getHowitters = async () => {
    const dbHowitter = await dbService.collection("howitter").get();
    dbHowitter.forEach((document) => {
      const howitterObject = {
        ...document.data(),
        id: document.id,
      };
      setHowitters((prev: ???) => [howitterObject, ...prev]); //What should I put in the "prev" type?
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getHowitters();
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
       {howitters.map((howitter: IhowitterMessage) => (
          <div key={howitter.id}>
            <h4>{howitter.message}</h4>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
   );
};
```

If you console.log(howitters), it is as follows.

```js
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
    0: {message: "no", createAt: 1631367025550, id: "q2d9TTgh36mgFZwMQ5EA"}
    1: {createAt: 1631365463319, message: "Good", id: "nCABFp1v3dP73gIbckpp"}
    2: {message: "hey", createAt: 1631367021665, id: "dmNBa6C8NwhDQDYDOP36"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's similar to your state's type**

Because `prev` is your previous state of `howitters` so you could put `IhowitterMessage[]` there too:

```
setHowitters((prev: IhowitterMessage[]) =>
```

Comment: Argument of type '(prev: IhowitterMessage[]) => { id: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IhowitterMessage[]>'.
  Type '(prev: IhowitterMessage[]) => { id: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IhowitterMessage[]) => IhowitterMessage[]'.
    Type '{ id: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IhowitterMessage[]'.
      Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IhowitterMessage': message, createAt  TS2345